# Сколько раз выполнится валидация и какое ожидать сообщение в случае не пройденной валидации?

Tags: java, валидация, аннотации

Есть валидационная аннотация `@Proverka`:

```
public class Person{

   private int id;

   @Valid
   @Proverka(message="Контакт заполнен не верно", group={Create.class})
   private Contact contact;

   //... остальной код
}

@Proverka(message="контакт неправельно заполнен", group={Create.class})
public class Contact{
   private int id;    

   private boolean isEmail;

   private String value;

   //... остальной код
}
```

сама аннотация объявлена так:

```
@Target({TYPE,FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {ProverkaValidatorImpl.class})
public @interface Proverka {

  String message() default "стандартное сообщение";

  Class<?>[] groups() default {};

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}


public class ProverkaValidatorImpl implements ConstraintValidator<Proverka, Contact> {

  @Override
  public void initialize(Proverka validateAddressByFias) {
    //initialize
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(Contact contact, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    // проверяет контакт по двум полям  isEmail и value
  }
}
```

контроллер примерно такой:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController { 

  @RequestMapping(
  value = {"/validate"},
  method = {RequestMethod.POST},
  consumes = {"application/json"},
  produces = {"application/json"}
  )
  public Person validatePerson(@PathVariable Long personId,
      @RequestBody @Validated(Create.class) Person person) {
    return person;
  }
}
```

Сколько раз будет выполнена валидация для объекта класса `Contact` если мы вызовем из контроллера метод валидации для объекта класса `Person`?

Какое сообщение ожидать в случае неправильно заполненного контакта? (возможно 3 варианта)

Comment: Сколько раз вы создаёт класс в контроллере?

Comment: @Roman C - я добавил примерный код контроллера в вопрос

Comment: Еще добавь исходный код для класса `Create`.

Comment: @Roman - смысла в коде класса Create- нет...  так как это группа для валидации.... там вообще может быть интерфейс без методов

Comment: тогда это вопрос к  дебагеру.